# Laravel Authorization header is missing

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-passport

I have implemented passport in my application and am using postman to test the api. However the Authorization header is missing among the headers. below is my

.htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]


# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

When i try this

```
Route::get('/setup', function (Request $request){
var_dump($request->headers);
});
```

i get this

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\HeaderBag)#44 (2) {
  ["headers":protected]=>
  array(8) {
["host"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "162.243.23.252"
}
["connection"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "keep-alive"
}
["accept"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "application/json"
}
["cache-control"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "no-cache"
}
["user-agent"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(105) "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36"
}
["postman-token"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "acac2f9b-9c71-fb9a-ebd5-62516eb4fd36"
}
["accept-encoding"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(19) "gzip, deflate, sdch"
}

 ["accept-language"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "en-US,en;q=0.8"
}
  }

["cacheControl":protected]=>
  array(1) {
["no-cache"]=>
bool(true)
  }
}
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score -2):

Why are you using apache to solve that?

Laravel handles the passport authentication: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: I am using laravel passport for authentication, but Authorization am unable to access the Authorization header. Note: the code works fine on my local machine, its only on the server that am unable to access the Authorization header